# Random result display PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a site that matches up users, just like any dating website. Except, I would like the users matches to randomly be displayed 1 at a time. Like they just click next until the come across a result they like. I know how to query the results in a list format but what sort of code would I need to use to randomly display their match's profiles, randomly chosen (based on the match score), one at a time? I am using PHP. Thanks! If you even tell me what to look up that would be great!

Comment: Can you give us some insights in your database?

Comment: I am using mySQL, would you like table structures?

Comment: I'm assuming you store the 'match score' in your database, could you make it more concrete what you actually want? 'randomly chosen based on the mach score', what do you *exactly* mean by that.

Comment: the score is not stored, it is created. when the query is run it searches through all of the users. users are matched based upon interests. each interest is given a value of 1. using an if statement, for each value the users have in common, the match score goes up by one. results are then displayed based on score

Comment: so I, I guess, randomly displaying users isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You **SHOULD NOT** use mysql's `ORDER BY RAND()` clause because it's slow, it's better to act like this:

1. select max(id) from profiles
2. select profile.* from profiles where profile.id = mt_rand(0, MAX_ID)

will be much more better for performance

Comment: You are however assuming the id's are incremented perfectly, and there are no gaps. This wouldnt be the case when you delete a user for example.

Comment: Why that wouldn't be the case? You use a loop to find id which exists... Even if you have a lot of "id holes" you can select all ids into some [temporary] table and get random from there

Comment: The second query wouldnt produce any result in case of a `hole`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a "complex" mysql request.. You can just add an `ORDER BY RAND()`, and process that list using ajax for instance.

Answer (score 0):

[rand](http://php.net/rand)

or [mt_rand](http://php.net/mt_rand)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE .... search conditions ...
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

Is the easiest, but most likely least efficient method of doing this. Re run the query each time they click next and you'll get a random entry of the matches. Note that this won't prevent duplicates from showing up, which is very likely if there's very few matches.